# how to apply an if statement to every value in a column and update a different row based on the the value

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['0','1','2','3','4'],'col2': ['10','20','30','40','50'], 'col3': 0})
```

How can I change the value in col3 to 1 under the condition that the value in col1 is less than 3 and col 2 is greater than 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `loc`

```
df.loc[(df['col1'] < 3) & (df['col2'] > 15), 'col3']  = 1
```

---

If you have strings, you can

```
df = df.astype(float)
```

or do this per column if you have other non-numeric columns in your data set.

Comment: If they are strings, then sure thing!

Comment: what if one of the values is a string such as 'abcd' astype isn't working how do I change it?

Comment: @SkandanVecham use `pd.to_numeric`: `df['col1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col1'], errors='coerce')`

Comment: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().     df.loc[df['NGPC PT'] <5 and df['NGPC PT'] > 1 and df['SC'] >5 and df['SC']<2,'RULE OF NGPC'] ='SO'. Thats the error its giving me.

Comment: It's not "and", but "&"

Comment: what do I do about or signs

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas `apply` with a lambda function that takes row as input:

```
In [3]: import pandas as pd

In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['0','1','2','3','4'],'col2': ['10','20','30','40','50'
   ...: ], 'col3': 0})
In [5]: df = df.astype('int')

In [6]: df['col3'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if (x['col1'] < 3) and (x['col2'] > 15) else 0,
    ...:  axis=1)
In [7]: df
Out[7]:
   col1  col2  col3
0     0    10     0
1     1    20     1
2     2    30     1
3     3    40     0
4     4    50     0
```

Comment: I'd recommend against using `apply`, since it's not vectorized (it's basically a for loop over the data) and gets pretty slow with big datasets :)

Comment: agree but depends on use cases. For beginner and small df, apply can be intuitive.